# Spearman or Kendall's tau-b correlation instead of simple Regression

Tags: regression, linear-model, normality-assumption, spearman-rho, kendall-tau

Let's assume we make a regression, but the data does not fulfill the assumptions of normality and linearity.

Is it possible to use **Spearman** or **Kendall's tau-b** correlation instead of a regression? Especially if it is a simple regression.

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can, but it's kind of apples and oranges. Correlation coefficients provide only a measure of association between two variables, whereas a regression model provides coefficients, predictions, etc. The linear equivalent of Spearman and Kendall correlation is Pearson correlation. The ordinal equivalent of OLS regression is quantile regression.